# ASP.NET MVC3 Validation of nested view model object fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model that looks like this:

```
public class VenueIndexViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public VenueAddViewModel Venue;
    ...
}

public class VenueAddViewModel
{
    ...
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In my view, I'm rendering a form with with a drop down list for this property like so:

```
using (var form = Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Venue.State, Model.GetStates())
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Venue.State)
    ...
}
```

This works, but the problem is that the the Required attribute on the view model appears to be ignored. If I look at the HTML, the data-val-* attributes are missing as well.

```
<select id="Venue_State" name="Venue.State">...</select>
```

However, if I change the rendering to a textbox...

```
using (var form = Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    ...
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Venue.State)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Venue.State)
    ...
}
```

I see the expected data-val-* attributes and the validation works:

```
<input data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="This field is required" 
    id="Venue_State" name="Venue.State" type="text" value="">
```

I should note that I have other view models elsewhere that use DropDownListFor with a flat view model (no nested objects) and the validation works fine there, so I'm thinking I've hit a bug in the MVC validation handling for drop down lists when using a nested view model.  Can anyone confirm / advise?

Comment: I just confirmed that if I move the form code to a partial view and pass it the exact view model it needs (VenueAddViewModel instead of VenueIndexViewModel), the validation attributes appear fine. However, I'm still not sure if I was doing something incorrectly above or if I've really encountered a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't have client side validation on nested objects. And a quick google search seems to confirm that.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1737269.aspx/1

Comment: That's fine and dandy, but it DID work for plain text fields. I'm guessing that was accidental, and support was never officially coded for nested objects, so what I perceived as a bug is really just an untested / unsupported scenario.