# Regex on data annotation behaves differently on sub properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have the following model on my website

```
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("E-Mail")]
        [MaxLength(60)]
        [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid e-mail")]
        public string MailAddress { get; set; }

        public UserInfo userInfo{ get; set; }
    }
public class UserInfo 
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
        public int UserProfileUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }


    [UIHint("PhoneNumbers")]
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
[...]
    }
public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [DisplayName("Téléphone")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[+]?[0-9\s]{2,20}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int UserInfoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserInfoId")]
    public Physician UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When I register a user, I have the following view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailAddressTemp)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MailAddressTemp)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailAddressTemp)
</div>
```

And the validation is ok

[image: Mail validation during registration]

However, when I try to modify the mail address from another view

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserProfile.MailAddress)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserProfile.MailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserProfile.MailAddress)
</div>
```

It doesn't work with the exact same mail address
[image]

Can someone explain it to me why regex validation doesn't work on sub properties?

Btw, I do have validation for the phone numbers during the registration and the modification of the account.

Thank you

Comment: You can't have client side validation on nested objects. The similar issue already been described here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153252/applying-data-annotations-to-sub-properties-of-the-view-model-in-mvc

Comment: What you can do is to create a PartialView strongly typed to UserProfile and then pass your nested UserProfile object to this PartialView. You can also use some third-party validation library which enables client-side validation on nested objects (e.g. FluentValidation).

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer more elaborate:

1. You can't have client side validation on nested objects.
2. You can replace DataAnnotations with some third-party validation library like e.g. FluentValidatio.
3. In general DataAnnotations are used for simple scenarios. In case of more complex scenarios like this with nested objects you could implement IValidatableObject interface.

Comment: What puzzle me is that it works with my nested property "PhoneNumber". I update the question

Comment: I've updated the models and the validation works with the phone numbers. What I don't understand is that the validation is always false for the mail address.

Comment: Ok I found the mistake. I have extracted the regex into a constant to be sure that I use the same one. And that solved the problem. Thanks for your help! So I do have validation on my nested property.

Comment: I am happy to hear this :) Just to be sure - your question was connected with client-side or server-side validation?

Comment: The problem occurred on the client side validation